# How to exclude locale from anguar2-moment?

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

In my ionic-angular application I am using angular2-moment.
When lookin at the source maps It includes locales which in turn increases the size of my vendor.js

I want to exclude locale, how to do this ? I have followed this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6137) in which TomDemulierChe has commented to include in paths of `tsconfig.json` but it displays errors as baseUrl is not included.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2416

Comment: That issue uses webpack, I am using typescript which inturn uses webpack.So How to use this in angular project?